# Find the name of the Imported DLLs using PE Headers

Tags: c++, windows, pointers, types, portable-executable

A Few days back I have started with Windows System Programming using c++. Hence, thought of building a utility to grab the PE Headers of an exe file.
And now I am stuck with the *Image_Import_descriptor* structure.

What I want is to get the names of the DLL files(modules) imported by the exe. And below is the code I am using to get those names:

```
        DWORD Image_Import_Descriptor_addr = (DWORD)ntHeader + (DWORD)sizeof(ntHeader->FileHeader) + (DWORD)ntHeader->FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader + (DWORD)ntHeader->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].Size;
        importImageDescriptor = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)Image_Import_Descriptor_addr;
```

To get the RVA of the *name*:

```
        DWORD name = importImageDescriptor->Name;
        printf("\n\n\n\t\t (((Module Name)): %X", name);
```

Gives an output:
**4778B00**

Hope untill now everything was fine technically.

However, my motive is to print the DLL names(like kernel32.dll).
Can anyone help me out how to get the names of the DLL ?

My workarounds:

```
            LPCSTR snames = (LPCSTR)name;          
            printf("\n\n\n\t\t (((Module Name)): %s", *snames);
```

But this is giving me an error: *Access Violation*

I am getting confused with the pointers and Datatype conversions. A help is much appreciated.

Comment: You are using the `Name` offset wrong. See for example [How to read Import Directory Table in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17457077).

Comment: Thanks, but can you make it more simpler? How is the Name offset wrong in my case?

Comment: `Name` is an RVA to the actual name, so you can't just cast `(LPCSTR)name`. The necessary code to convert it to an offset is in the previous link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the technique from 'ired' security blogs. Below is the working code.

```
HANDLE h_File = CreateFile(L"testing.exe", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

if (!h_File) {
    printf("\nERROR : Could not open the file specified\n");
}

//Mapping Given EXE file to Memory
HANDLE hMapObject = CreateFileMapping(h_File, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);
LPVOID basepointer = (char*)MapViewOfFile(hMapObject, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);

//PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dos_header;        
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dos_header = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)basepointer;
printf("Magic number - %X\n", dos_header->e_magic); 

printf("DOS HEADER: IMAGE NT HEADER offset(Relative Address) - %X\n", dos_header->e_lfanew);  //DOS header working fine...

//PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS ntHeader;         
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS nt_header = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD)basepointer + dos_header->e_lfanew);
printf("NT HEADER: Signature %x\n", nt_header->Signature);

PIMAGE_FILE_HEADER file_header = (PIMAGE_FILE_HEADER)((DWORD)basepointer + dos_header->e_lfanew + sizeof(nt_header->Signature));
printf("FILE HEADER: Machine %x\n", file_header->Machine);

PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER optional_header = (PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER)((DWORD)basepointer + dos_header->e_lfanew + sizeof(nt_header->Signature) + sizeof(nt_header->FileHeader));
printf("OPTIONAL HEADER: Image Base %x\n", optional_header->ImageBase);

PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER section_header = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)((DWORD)basepointer + dos_header->e_lfanew + sizeof(nt_header->Signature) + sizeof(nt_header->FileHeader) + sizeof(nt_header->OptionalHeader));
DWORD numberofsections = file_header->NumberOfSections;
printf("Section Header: Number of Sections %x\n", file_header->NumberOfSections);


    
for (int j = 0; j < optional_header->NumberOfRvaAndSizes;j++) {
    printf("Data Directory: Virtual Address: %x\t\n", optional_header->DataDirectory[j].VirtualAddress);
}

DWORD RVAimport_directory = nt_header->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[1].VirtualAddress;
//printf("RVAimport_directory %x", RVAimport_directory);

PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER import_section = {};
for (int i = 1; i <= numberofsections; i++, section_header++) {
    printf("Section Header: Section Name %s\n", section_header->Name);

    if (RVAimport_directory >= section_header->VirtualAddress && RVAimport_directory < section_header->VirtualAddress + section_header->Misc.VirtualSize) {

        import_section = section_header;
    }
    //section_header += (DWORD)sizeof(PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER);
}

DWORD import_table_offset = (DWORD)basepointer + import_section->PointerToRawData;
//imageBaseAddress + pointerToRawDataOfTheSectionContainingRVAofInterest + (RVAofInterest - SectionContainingRVAofInterest.VirtualAddress

importImageDescriptor = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)(import_table_offset + (nt_header->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[1].VirtualAddress - import_section->VirtualAddress));

//DLL Imports
for (;importImageDescriptor->Name != 0 ; importImageDescriptor++) {
    DWORD Imported_DLL = import_table_offset + (importImageDescriptor->Name - import_section->VirtualAddress);
    printf("Imported DLLs: %s\n", Imported_DLL);
```